# ios - is UIActivityIndicatorView supposed to just show up by default?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

Usually when I worked with UIActivityIndicatorView in the past, I had to make it hide/show.

But now I dragged it into my screen on the storyboard, and when I run the emulator, it just shows up on the screen without spinning.

Any idea why that would happen and what I might have done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `hidesWhenStopped` set to `NO`?

`UIActivityIndicatorView`'s have a property `hidesWhenStopped` which, by default, is set to `YES`- so when the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is not animating, it will be hidden.

Perhaps you managed to accidentally change this property to `NO`?